# which of these for-loops is more efficient/the better way to code the loop

Tags: python

Which is better between these two for-loops in python?  I have "assumed" the compiler would be smart enough to do the json.loads just one time and, on its own, store the data in a temporary variable so that it could maintain the iterator needed to process the for-loop.  But then I started to wonder if I was mistaken and that the first style would be causing unwarranted extra steps.

```
for employee in json.loads(response.content)
```

OR

```
temp = json.loads(response.content)
   for employee in temp
```

Comment: They are practically the same. Of course, in the second case, the loaded content's reference count will will stay at 1 (although, will drop to 0 if it is inside a function and the function terminates).

Comment: Anyway, I think you are worried that `json.load` gets called at each iteration of the loop. It definitely doesn't.

Comment: It's not just a matter of being "smart enough". It's required by the language.

Comment: Practically, I would only use the second option if I needed to check or use the contents of `temp` more than once

Comment: On what metric are you defining "better way"?

Comment: @G.Anderson I would use it to give it a descriptive name even if I'm not using it later.

Comment: @G.Anderson - Its also used to avoid pep8 line lengths.

Comment: It's kind of a moot point, if we're talking about a `requests.Response` object. `for employee in response.json():`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although both are essentially the same, there's one good reason to favor a temporary value: it lets you catch any errors in the call to `json.loads` before trying to iterate over the result. This is consistent with keeping the code in a `try` statement as focused as possible.

```
try:
    employees = json.loads(response.content)
except JSONDecodeError:
    # Maybe log an error message
    # Maybe just reraise the exception
    employees = []

for employee in employees:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly clear from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> ```
> for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
>               ["else" ":" suite]
> ```
>
> The expression list is evaluated once;

So your worry is unfounded, and the first way is preferable unless you want to reuse the data again or writing it on the `for` line would make the line too long.